# Getting error in trigger recursion for example if I create account and than update it. It will give me the concatenation of both insert one and update

Tags: apex, trigger, trigger-oldmap

```
Trigger accpre on account(before insert, before update){
    list<account> acclist=new list<account>();

    for(Account acc:Trigger.new){
        if(acc.phone!=Trigger.oldMap.get(acc.id).phone){
          acc.name=acc.name+acc.phone;
        }
        acclist.add(acc);
    }
    update acclist;
}
```

Comment: Please refrain from using all caps.

Comment: You do not need to perform a DML update for the same records that were passed into the trigger. Indeed, this should give you an error. Just update the fields you need to update.

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to update a field of the record(s) being passed to the trigger, just do that; there's no need to perform a DML operation. These additional updates will simply get rolled in with the rest of it (because you are in the "before" phase):

```
trigger accpre on Account(before insert, before update) {
    // In "before insert" there are no IDs. You can use this, or that Trigger.oldMap
    // is null, to detect "before insert" vs "before update"
    for (Account acc : Trigger.new) {
        // The first part says when it is "insert" and the second is for when
        // it is an update and the phone number must have changed
        if (acc.Id == null || acc.Phone != Trigger.oldMap.get(acc.Id).Phone) {
            // Add the phone number to the name if there is a phone number
            // defined
            if (acc.Phone != null) {
                acc.Name += acc.Phone;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this trigger has a flaw that it will keep adding modified phone numbers to the account name, so if you had +112345678909 as the first number and change to +1909876543210 as the second, without also changing the name you will get a name like:

> My Account Name+112345678909+1909876543210

You may want to remember the original name, or ensure that you remove the old phone number from the end of the name first when adding a new number.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this happens is pretty straightforward. The trigger does `DML on those records too` whose Phone fields were not even updated. The fix is pretty straightforward as well once you know why it is happening, you just need to prevent updating those accounts which were not updated.
Your code had a few additional issues.

1. `Trigger.oldMap` is null in before insert context
2. You may not want to add `null` in Account Name when Phone is updated to null.

Update:
Since you already are in before context. You do not need to make any DML at all. You can simply make changes to the trigger context variables since they're going to commit.

```
    trigger AccountTrigger on Account (before insert, before update){
            for(Account acc: (Account[])Trigger.new){
                if(Trigger.oldMap == null || (acc.Phone != Trigger.oldMap.get(acc.Id).Phone)){    
                    acc.Name = acc.Name + (String.isBlank(acc.Phone) ? '' : acc.Phone);
                 }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Trying to update the input Accounts in a trigger via DML is going to fail. You'll get an error saying you're trying to modify the object already in the scope of the trigger. Additionally, since this covers "before insert" there won't be an Id on the account record in that case (only for "before update").

Comment: Correct i totally missed the context. :(